# Creating multiple, independent, threads on a form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to emulate a 'horse race' with VB Express 2013 which has exposed a gap in my understanding of how threads work with windows forms. The idea is that a blue square and a red square (the horses) race from left to right across a form (which has a white background) when a button on the form is pressed.  Each increment of movement should be (pseudo) randomly generated, so the winner should be unpredictable.

Here is the code I have used. The movement of the squares is indeed random, but they move together, not independently, so the race is always a tie.  If I include Randomize in only one of the thread procedures, it behaves more like a race but the winner is usually predictable.  Could someone please tell me what I am missing? Thanks in anticipation.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim t1 As System.Threading.Thread
        Dim t2 As System.Threading.Thread

        t1 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf RedHorse)
        t2 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf BlueHorse)

        t1.Start()
        t2.Start()

    End Sub

    Public Sub RedHorse()
        Randomize()
        Dim G As Graphics
        G = Me.CreateGraphics
        Dim bRed As Brush
        bRed = New SolidBrush(Color.Red)
        Dim bWhite As Brush
        bWhite = New SolidBrush(Color.White)

        Dim x1 As Integer
        x1 = 100

        G.FillRectangle(bWhite, x1, 100, 50, 50)

        Do Until x1 >= 800
            x1 = x1 + Rnd()
            G.FillRectangle(bRed, x1, 100, 50, 50)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
            G.FillRectangle(bWhite, x1, 100, 50, 50)
        Loop
    End Sub

    Public Sub BlueHorse()
        Randomize()
        Dim G As Graphics
        G = Me.CreateGraphics
        Dim bBlue As Brush
        bBlue = New SolidBrush(Color.Blue)
        Dim bWhite As Brush
        bWhite = New SolidBrush(Color.White)

        Dim x2 As Integer
        x2 = 100

        G.FillRectangle(bWhite, x2, 200, 50, 50)

        Do Until x2 >= 800
            x2 = x2 + Rnd()
            G.FillRectangle(bBlue, x2, 200, 50, 50)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
            G.FillRectangle(bWhite, x2, 200, 50, 50)
        Loop

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown

        Dim G As Graphics
        G = Me.CreateGraphics
        Dim bRed As Brush
        bRed = New SolidBrush(Color.Red)
        Dim bBlue As Brush
        bBlue = New SolidBrush(Color.Blue)

        G.FillRectangle(bRed, 100, 100, 50, 50)
        G.FillRectangle(bBlue, 100, 200, 50, 50)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Besides the Randomize issue, I don't think that you can update the graphics from threads. Do position computations in threads and use a timer to update HMI with computed positions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use Randomize, use the Random class, read up on this.  The basic problem was that the threads started at the same time and then slept for the same time between loops.  Here is your code with a few changes.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'Me.Width = 1000 'testing
        isWinner = -1

        Dim t1 As System.Threading.Thread
        Dim t2 As System.Threading.Thread

        t1 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf RedHorse)
        t2 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf BlueHorse)

        t1.Start()
        t2.Start()

    End Sub

    Dim prng As New Random
    Const maxMove As Integer = 21
    Const maxSleep As Integer = 51
    Dim isWinner As Integer = -1

    Public Sub RedHorse()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(prng.Next(maxSleep))
        Dim G As Graphics
        G = Me.CreateGraphics
        Dim bRed As Brush
        bRed = New SolidBrush(Color.Red)
        Dim bWhite As Brush
        bWhite = New SolidBrush(Color.White)

        Dim x1 As Integer
        x1 = 100

        G.FillRectangle(bWhite, x1, 100, 50, 50)

        Do While x1 < 800 AndAlso isWinner < 0
            x1 = x1 + prng.Next(maxMove)
            G.FillRectangle(bRed, x1, 100, 50, 50)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(prng.Next(maxSleep))
            G.FillRectangle(bWhite, x1, 100, 50, 50)
        Loop
        'G.FillRectangle(bRed, x1, 100, 50, 50)
        If isWinner < 0 Then
            isWinner = 1
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub BlueHorse()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(prng.Next(maxSleep))
        Dim G As Graphics
        G = Me.CreateGraphics
        Dim bBlue As Brush
        bBlue = New SolidBrush(Color.Blue)
        Dim bWhite As Brush
        bWhite = New SolidBrush(Color.White)

        Dim x2 As Integer
        x2 = 100

        G.FillRectangle(bWhite, x2, 200, 50, 50)

        Do While x2 < 800 AndAlso isWinner < 0
            x2 = x2 + prng.Next(maxMove)
            G.FillRectangle(bBlue, x2, 200, 50, 50)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(prng.Next(maxSleep))
            G.FillRectangle(bWhite, x2, 200, 50, 50)
        Loop
        'G.FillRectangle(bBlue, x2, 200, 50, 50)
        If isWinner < 0 Then
            isWinner = 2
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown

        Dim G As Graphics
        G = Me.CreateGraphics
        Dim bRed As Brush
        bRed = New SolidBrush(Color.Red)
        Dim bBlue As Brush
        bBlue = New SolidBrush(Color.Blue)

        G.FillRectangle(bRed, 100, 100, 50, 50)
        G.FillRectangle(bBlue, 100, 200, 50, 50)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks dbasnett for your improved code - it does exactly the job I want.  I see that, with the Random class, you have generated a set of random numbers in advance.  In this sense the result of each race is pre-ordained (but I guess it was anyway).  I still can't get my head around why my original attempt did not work; each 'horse' generated a random number to control its next move.  I presumed that this would be different for each horse because rnd was used on different threads???  Thanks again though.